# Regex - capturing repeated groups in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a tough time writing a C<sup>♯</sup> regular expression. I want to write an expression which can catch `abc`. For example, I have a string:

```
<a href="function(##abc##);function(##abc##)">
```

I want to capture `abc` and replace it with `xyz`.

I have tried something like `(")([^"]*)(##abc##)([^"]*)(")`

This captures the first occurrence of `abc` but not the second one. Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: btw: Your regex is overly complicated, a normal search and replace would do here as well.

Comment: C# .net is what i am using i want to use regex.replace function to work with this. is it possible?

Comment: i cant use it because i am working with xml and xslt.. i have to replace it with a diff value if it is in a tag or a diff value if it is not a tag :(

Comment: @llya kogan C# .net is what i am using i want to use regex.replace function to work with this. is it possible?  i am working with xml and xslt.. i have to replace it with a diff value if it is in a tag or a diff value if it is not a tag :(

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the additional information, instead of commenting on your own question. This isn't a chatroom, it's a question and answer site. Provide information and  ask your question in the question  text itself, and if more information or details need to be added later, you can edit your question to provide them. It makes it much easier for people reading your question who want to help if all your information is in one place instead of scattered among the comments. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

In some programming-languages you have to set a global-Flag to achieve that all occurences are matched, not only the first one. Often the Flag is a „g“

Comment: That doesn't apply here.  `Regex#Replace` (the instance methods, not the static ones) is global by default but you can specify a maximum number of replacements to make.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a match evaluator as such:

```
private class Replacer
{
    private bool inQuotes;
    public string Replace( Match m ){
        if( m.Value == "\"" ){
            inQuotes = ! inQuotes;
        }else if ( inQuotes && m.Value == "##abc##" ){
            return "##xyz##";
        }
        return m.Value;
    }
}

input = "<a href=\"function(##abc##);function(##abc##)\">";
Console.WriteLine( Regex.Replace( input, "\"|(##abc##)", (new Replacer()).Replace ) );
```

Which outputs:

```
<a href="function(##xyz##);function(##xyz##)">
```

Although if you're working with XML you probably want to use XPath to first find the text between the quotes, and then use a regex or direct string replace to do the replacement. If you're working with HTML (which isn't XHTML) you can use a library like http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ to do something similar.

Alternatively (and probably the worst option) to use a single regex this seems to do the job but isn't pretty:

```
Match match = (new Regex("(?:\")([^\"]*?(##abc##))+[^\"]*(?:\")")).Match(input);
```

You can then iterate over each of the matches in match.Groups[2].Captures. Though you would have to do the actual replacement manually based using the index and length of each capture.

Comment: can u help me pass additional arguments to the matchevaluator.. i know its a delegate an we can pass it.. but i want to pass 2 strings as arguments can u help me?